# add 2 values to URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, action

In my AvailabilityController I want to use an actionLink to add 2 values to the URL when 'Next' is clicked

```
<a href='<%: Url.Action("Index", "Availability", new {month=10&year=2013}) %>'>
            <button>Next</button>
     </a>


[Themed]
    public ActionResult Index(int month, int year)
    {
```

will this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite unclear why your question is tagged with `razor` where in your example you are using the WebForms view engine. Those are 2 completely different things and next time please be more specific.

So just separate the values with comma in order to create an anonymous object:

```
<a href="<%: Url.Action("Index", "Availability", new { month = 10, year = 2013 }) %>">
    <button>Next</button>
</a>
```

which would generate (assuming default routing):

```
<a href="/Availability/Index?month=10&amp;year=2013">
    <button>Next</button>
</a>
```

Or if you are in fact using the Razor view engine then make sure you have the proper syntax:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Availability", new { month = 10, year = 2013 })">
    <button>Next</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use this

```
<a href="<%: Url.Action("Index", "Availability", new { month = 10, year = 2013 }) %>">
<button>Next</button></a>
```

or

```
<a href="<%: Url.Content("~/Availability/Index?month=10&year=2013")%>">
<button>Next</button></a>
```